# Error while publishing azure web site using web deploy

Tags: visual-studio, azure, azure-web-app-service, webdeploy

I am using Web Publish to deploy website on Azure WebSites using Visual Studio 2013.
While publishing sometimes I get following error
"chunked encoding upload is not supported on the http/1.0"

I have observed that when I uncheck "bypass proxy server for local addresses" checkbox in LAN settings in IE, this error goes away.
But this is intermittent. Sometimes this solution works and publishes the site successfully and sometimes not.

Is there anyway to fix this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

are you behind some type of proxy or firewall? If so are you able to disable it temporarily and test to see if you still get the issue?

Possibly third party firewall software running directly on your machine?

Being it is happening intermittently, it is most likely a connectivity / networking issue on your end.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a web debugger, try closing it and try again.
For me the same problem was caused by Charles Web Debugger to be specific.